# Status of András Faragó’s (second) claimed proof that NP=RP

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, np

In 2020, András Faragó claimed to have proved that NP = RP ([discussion](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/47337/implications-of-proving-np-rp-on-complexity-theory); [v1 of the paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2008.00601v1)); the paper was later retracted due to a counterexample to theorem 1.

A few days ago, Faragó posted another [claimed proof](https://arxiv.org/abs/2312.11838) to the arXiv. Perhaps, given the first attempt, less attention will be paid to this second paper, but I still wonder whether any similar (or dissimilar) problems have been found.

Comment: Ancient Greeks [had a story](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Boy_Who_Cried_Wolf) that is pertinent to this situation.

Comment: The expression “Note that our sampling algorithm *(if correct)* has extremely surprising consequences” (emphasis mine) is not exactly inviting confidence.

Comment: Well, the author made a mistake once. Maybe he is just trying to be modest :)

Comment: To anybody wondering why the preprint was not retracted: I wrote to Faragó, but I believe he must have been quite ill by that point, and it seems that he has now, sadly, [died](https://www.gofundme.com/f/in-memory-of-dr-andras-farago).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It seems to me that Theorem 1 in the paper is false for essentially the same reasons as the Peres example showed in the last version.

Theorem 1 seems to say the following, at least in a special case. Let $S$ be some finite domain and let $H\subset S$ denote some subset. Let $X$ be a random $n\times n$ array with entries in $S$ with the property that each $X_{i,j}$ has some fixed marginal distribution $\mathcal{D}$ on $S$ such that $H$ has positive probability, and let $\alpha$ denote the conditional distribution of $X_{i,j}$ obtained by conditioning on $X_{i,j}\in H$ (which is well-defined since $H$ has positive probability). Moreover, suppose that the entries of the matrix are jointly independent across rows (but the entries within a row need not be independent). An $H$-perfect matching of $X$ (Def. 5) is a bijection $\sigma:[n]\to [n]$ such that $X_{i,\sigma(i)}\in H$ for all $i\in [n]$. Let $M(X)$ denote the (random, possibly empty) set of $H$-perfect matchings of $X$.

Theorem 1 appears to claim that, *under just these assumptions*, conditioned on $X$ having a $H$-perfect matching, the distribution of $(X_{1,\tau(1)},\ldots,X_{n,\tau(n)})$ factorizes as a product measure over $\alpha$, where $\tau$ is chosen uniformly at random among all $H$-perfect matchings of $X$. That is, for any $(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\in H^n$,
\begin{equation*}
\Pr_{\tau\sim \mathsf{U}[M(X)]}\left(X_{i,\tau(i)}=x_i,\forall i\in [n]\bigg\vert M(X)\neq \emptyset\right)=\prod_{i=1}^n \alpha(x_i),
\end{equation*}
where $\mathsf{U}[M(X)]$ is the uniform distribution over $H$-perfect matchings in $X$.

For a counterexample, just take Peres' example verbatim. Let $S=\{1,2,3\}$ and $H=\{1,2\}$. For each row of $X$ independently, with probability $1/2$, sample the entries of the row i.i.d. uniformly $1$ or $2$, and with probability $1/2$, sample the entries of the row i.i.d. uniformly $1$ or $3$. Call the first situation $A$ and the second situation $B$. The marginal law of each $X_{i,j}$ is clearly $1$ with probability $1/2$ and $2$ or $3$ with probability $1/4$ each. The conditional law $\alpha$ of $X_{i,j}$ given $X_{i,j}\in H$ is $X_{i,j}=1$ with probability $2/3$ and $X_{i,j}=2$ with probability $1/3$.

Let's compute
\begin{equation*}
\Pr_{\tau\sim \mathsf{U}[M(X)]}\left(X_{i,\tau(i)}=2,\forall i\in [n]\bigg\vert M(X)\neq \emptyset\right).
\end{equation*}
Theorem 1 appears to claim that this should be $\alpha(2)^n=(1/3)^n$.

It's easy to see that that the probability $M(X)\neq \emptyset$ is $1-o(1)$ by comparison with the probability that a random bipartite graph with $1/2$ edge probability has a perfect matching via the obvious coupling. Now, we have
\begin{equation*}
\Pr_{\tau\sim \mathsf{U}[M(X)]}\left(X_{i,\tau(i)}=2,\forall i\in [n]\bigg\vert M(X)\neq \emptyset\right)=\Pr_{\tau\sim U[M(X)]}\left(X_{i,\tau(i)}=2,\forall i\in [n]\,\land\, \text{all rows sampled via $A$}\bigg\vert M(X)\neq \emptyset\right).
\end{equation*}
This holds simply because if all entries in any perfect matching are $2$, all rows must have been sampled according to situation $A$. We thus have
\begin{equation*}
\Pr_{\tau\sim \mathsf{U}[M(X)]}\left(X_{i,\tau(i)}=2,\forall i\in [n]\,\land\, \text{all rows sampled via $A$}\bigg\vert M(X)\neq \emptyset\right)=\Pr_{\tau\sim U[M(X)]}\left(X_{i,\tau(i)}=2,\forall i\in [n]\bigg\vert \text{all rows sampled via $A$}\,\land\,M(X)\neq \emptyset\right)\cdot\Pr\left(\text{all rows sampled via $A$}\vert M(X)\neq \emptyset\right).
\end{equation*}
For the second factor, by Bayes' rule, we have
\begin{equation*}
\Pr\left(\text{all rows sampled via $A$}\vert M(X)\neq \emptyset\right)= \frac{\Pr\left(\text{all rows sampled via $A$}\right)}{\Pr(M(X)\neq \emptyset)}=\frac{1+o(1)}{2^n},
\end{equation*}
since the event that all rows are sampled via $A$ implies there exists a $H$-perfect matching.
For the first factor, note that
\begin{equation*}
\Pr_{\tau\sim U[M(X)]}\left(X_{i,\tau(i)}=2,\forall i\in [n]\bigg\vert \text{all rows sampled via $A$}\,\land\,M(X)\neq \emptyset\right)=\Pr_{\tau\sim U[M(X)]}\left(X_{i,\tau(i)}=2,\forall i\in [n]\bigg\vert \text{all rows sampled via $A$}\right),
\end{equation*}
since again, the event that all rows are sampled via $A$ implies the existence of $H$-perfect matchings. In fact, all perfect matchings are valid if $A$ occurs since necessarily every entry is in $H$ by construction. But given $A$ occurs for every row, the joint law of all entries of the matrix is i.i.d. uniform over $1$ or $2$, independent of the choice of uniform random matching. So we have
\begin{equation*}
\Pr_{\tau\sim U[M(X)]}\left(X_{i,\tau(i)}=2,\forall i\in [n]\bigg\vert \text{all rows sampled via $A$}\right)=\frac{1}{2^n}.
\end{equation*}
Putting it together, we find that
$\Pr_{\tau\sim \mathsf{U}[M(X)]}\left(X_{i,\tau(i)}=2,\forall i\in [n]\bigg\vert M(X)\neq \emptyset\right)=\frac{1+o(1)}{4^n}\ll \frac{1}{3^n}$.

Comment: Thank you; I shall accept this answer once I’ve read it more closely.